# IP and Ethernet endianness

Tags: ip, ethernet, osi

I'm completely new to the topic, I've read that Ethernet sends Bytes in a Big-Endian way, but that bits are sent with Little-Endian. I've also read that IPv4 uses Big_endian order. So my question is, how can IP protocol stay on an Ethernet layer if they (IP layer and Ethernet) manage bits in different ways?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the term *endianness* here. There's no general word size like with CPUs.

Ethernet sends bytes as a bit stream, with the least significant bit first, with the notable exception of the FCS. In multi-octet fields, octets are ordered most significant octet first.

IP uses the same most-significant-octet-first order, where that matters. It doesn't (really) define a bit order as it interfaces with the underlying protocol on the octet/byte level.

For Ethernet, the IP packet with headers is only payload, a bunch of bytes, so whatever rules apply within the payload doesn't matter. The only thing that matters is that the bit and byte orders are well defined and apply to the whole network, to enable data exchange.

Comment: I'm sorry for ingenuity but as I said I'm completely naive. But in what sense "whatever rules apply within the payload doesn't matter"? the superior layer will have to read that payload, so ins't it a problem if ethernet level has sent (and saved (?)) data in an inverted bit order than the one used by the upper layer?

Comment: Ethernet is the lower layer here. Generally, a lower layer doesn't understand nor care for any headers, data or anything else in an upper layer - it's all just payload. And as explained, Ethernet's physical layer is the only one involved with bit order.

Comment: From what I have learnt data is passed from layer to layer as packets (the topic of n-PDU and so on). Having this image in my mind I see the packet transferred from Ethernet level to network layer in a packet in which bits are arranged in a little endian fashion and I'm not understanding how network layer could understand it if the packet that is received has been "written" in a language different from what the level uses. What am I missing with this view ?

Comment: @mizius *Payload* is passed between layers as just an array of bytes. Packetization may even be a service provided by a lower layer. What those bytes mean and how they are arranged is not of any consequence nor even understood by the lower layer.

Comment: Lower layers encapsulate upper layers, like putting a letter in an envelope.

Comment: ... without being able to read the actual letter, only where it's supposed to go.

Comment: I see the physical layer as the one that, viewing by analogy PDUs as letters, has to rewrite manually the letter that is being sent over the network for the receiver, so if in the letter was written the sequence 10100 then Ethernet would send this sequence as 00101 through the channel. And the receiving end (since Ethernet is at physical layer) would save it as 00101. So when this letter will be passed to the upper level, even if as you said the payload was not used by the physical layer, the letter will be nonetheless written in an order that for IP protocol is meaningless. What's wrong there

Comment: @mizius The bit order is only relevant at the physical layer. Both transmitter and receiver need to use the same order, so bytes are passed transparently. Bits are line encoded, but that doesn't really matter here. The encoding PCS sublayer is part of the physical layer and the receiver side reverses the encoding that the transmitter used.

Comment: ok something is becoming clearer now, but when you say "the receiver side reverses the encoding that the transmitter used" this means that data are saved in a big endian fashion at the bit level in any case ? even if they are transmitted with little endian (on a bit level) like with ethernet? Besides I can't get how network layer could not mind about the bit order, how does he reads packets if not bit by bit?

Comment: The network layer passes a byte-sized buffer to the data link layer, and on the receiver side, the same byte-sized buffer is passed from the data link layer to the network layer. Each layer passes data transparently for the next higher layer.

Comment: Look at it this way: does TCP care whether your application-layer protocol passes the number 1234 as decimal string "1234", as hex "0x04d2", or octal string "02322", or binary? Little-endian or big-endian? It doesn't matter any which way. The only thing that matters is that the same protocols in the same layer understand each other.

Comment: ok great, but correct me if I'm wrong this means that Ethernet has to revers bits ? I mean if he wants to give it transparently to the IP protocol as you said

Comment: There's nothing to reverse. Bits are clocked out 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7 and clocked in 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7.